# Minimum no of bits to represent -130 in 8086?

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, x86-16, negative-number

I need to know the **minimum** numbers of bits needed to represent **130** and **-130** in 8086.

- For 130 (usigned):
  This would be unsigned, so it's represented normally. 130 = 0x82 = 1000 0010b
  In this case the answer would be **8 bits**
- For -130 (signed): A negative number in 8086 is the second complement of the usigned number plus 1. So, first complement (not 0x82): 0111 1101b and plus 1 it would be 0111 1110b = 0x7E. In my oppinion you would need a *minimum* of just ***7 bits*** to represent -130. **Is this right ?** If the number is negative, shouldn't be the last bit enabled to know that the sign is negative ? This would require more than 7 bits.

If somebody knows the answer for sure, please let me know.

Comment: You need to specify a range for this question to make sense. So you want to represent all numbers {-130, ..., 130}? Also, the number of bits to represent a range of numbers is independent of the architecture (you can always store values after adding or subtracting some offset). Assuming that you mean this range, you would need ceil(log_2(130-(-130)+1)) bits, which is 9.

Comment: well, this is the question basically, it wierd I know, that's why I've asked it here. It's a question for the assembly exam, and that's basically all I know. Probably needed to know if it can be represented on 1 byte or word (AL or AX). The answer is to know the minimum number of bits, wanted to see if somebody might view the question from another angle.

Comment: You can encode numbers anyway you want.  Distinguishing between +130 and -130 requires only a single bit.  But if you want to be able to encode the *range* of numbers between -130..+130, 261 distinct values, then you need log2(261) = 9 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking the two's complement of a number, you must

- place an infinite number of 0 bits to the left
- invert all the bits
- add 1
- remove some of the infinite number of 1 bits, if desired

Let's apply this to the number -130. The bit pattern for 130 is

```
1000 0010
```

After placing an infinite number of 0's on the left it's

```
0000 0000 1000 0010
```

OK, so eight is slightly less than infinity, but you get the idea. Next invert to get

```
1111 1111 0111 1101
```

and add 1 to get

```
1111 1111 0111 1110
```

At this point you can remove some of the infinite 1's on the left, but you must keep at least one of them. So the shortest two's complement representation of -130 requires 9 bits.

```
1 0111 1110
```

If the question is what size register is needed on an x86 processor, then the answer is a 16-bit register.

Comment: wow, thanks ! sounds better now. So basically, I would need AX to represent it. Still ... if I do mov al, -130, it's not giving any error, and I think it should ... -130 doesn't fit in just a 8-bit register.

Comment: I assume that the assembler doesn't range check the number. Instead it just drops the upper bits. So `mov al, -130` is encoded as `mov al, 0x7e`, which is to say that `al` just gets the lower 8-bits of whatever number you specify.

Comment: I gotcha, so it's basically an assembler thing.

Comment: I have one more question about imul and idiv, do you have skype or something ? Would really appreciate if you could tell me what's the enigma for that one. I have the exam in like hour.

Comment: actually, adding a single 0 is enough. No need for infinite numbers of 0s. Because positive numbers (e.g. 130) in 2's complement start with a zero, negative with a one (e.g. -130)

Comment: edit: Okay, you may go for the infinite numbers of 0s, when you do not want to limit yourself to the minimum amount of needed bits.